# MongoDB parent / child relationinship and fast retrieval of parents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following models in mongoose, Book which belonds to a User.
When I Book.findAll(), I also want to retrieve information from the associated User. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
const user_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullname: { type: String },
  avatar: { type: String }
});
module.exports.User = mongoose.model("User", user_schema);


const book_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _uid: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true }
  text: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports.Book = mongoose.model("Book", book_schema);
```

I need to be able to do something like:

```
Book.findOne({...}).user.avatar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$lookup` for this kind of operations.

```
db.books.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "user_id", //User ID in users collection
         foreignField: "_uid",  //User ID in books collection
         as: "books_data"
       }
  }
])
```

Also, kindly have primary key values in both schemas:

```
const user_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id : {type : String },
  fullname: { type: String },
  avatar: { type: String }
});
```